# Boolean Variables in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to set up a simple boolean variable in js in order to control a few things however I am having some issues relating to when it is being fired. The boolean variable is changed whenever the user clicks a button which runs the function `changeVariable()`. The issue is that the alerts are firing on page load and not when the user clicks a button which runs the specified function. If anyone could take a look, that would be much appreciated.

Code is here:

```
var triggered = false;


function changeVariable() {
    triggered = ! triggered;
}


if (triggered = true) {
    alert(triggered);   
}

if(triggered = false) {
    alert(triggered);   
}
```

Comment: Use `===` for comparison, `=` is for _assignment_!

Comment: @Vohuman should that replace all instances of '=' or only for the if statements?

Comment: In fact, your alerts are out of the function scope, so they are being fired on page load.

Comment: @ojovirtual what does out of the function scope mean exactly? Sorry

Answer (score 2):

triggered = true it is an assignment. Use `==` or `===`.

`===` it checks for type also.

Comment: His alerts are out of a function so they will fire nonetheless.

Comment: Or better yet, don't use comparison when you already are working with booleans : `if (triggered) { ... }` is similar to `if (triggered == true) { ... }` and `if (!triggered) { ... }` to `if (triggered == false) { ... }`. You'll notice I used `==` rather than `===` because this syntax will coalesce to booleans, which might be hurtful in some cases.

Comment: I am now trying to use this but it gets error saying can't find variable despite everything being linked up correctly

Answer (score 1):

> The issue is that the alerts are firing on page load and not when the user clicks a button which runs the specified function.

That's because the code which performs the test and does the alert **is not inside the function**. Move it.

---

Aside: `=` is an assignment, to perform a comparison use `==` or `===`. For boolean tests, consider a simple `if (value)` instead. Also consider the use of `else` instead of duplicating a test with a negative modifier.